# iframes without sandbox attribute is a Vulnerability

Tags: chart.js

Many jQuery liraries uses iframes without sandbox attribute including Chart.js. Is there any option to apply sandbox attribute from the application where it is being used.

It is not possible to add sandbox="allow-same-origin" in js, as it is a js from 3rd Party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js [stopped using `iframe`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4596) in [version 2.7.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.7.0) (released almost 2 years ago at time of writing).

Upgrade your version of Chart.js to at least 2.7.0 to mitigate the problem.

Comment: This Works fine.